# MINOLTA XG-M not rewinding film

Tags: minolta

My Minolta XG-M is not rewinding the film into the canister. The rewind crank works, I loaded the film correctly because the advance lever advances the film.

Comment: Have you pushed down the rewind button? See page 40 of the manual: http://www.cameramanuals.org/minolta_pdf/minolta_xg-m.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Sorry you are having trouble rewinding the film. Assuming all the film has been exposed and now it is rewind time, take the camera to a one-hour photo lab or camera store and let them safely retrieve the film.

You think the film advance is OK, but this may not be true. It is often difficult to make this determination. If you are a frequent user, you likely will know by feel and visual signals that the film correctly advanced. More likely, the film was not loaded correctly or the film got damaged. We are talking about ripped out sprocket holes. Also, a mechanical malfunction dealing with the camera can occur.

You can safely open the camera yourself. Find a truly dark place. This can be a windowless room etc. Total darkness can be elusive. Since only a tiny amount of stray light will ruin the film, you must be sure the work area is safe. Best if you take in a chair. Take scissors and some aluminum foil in with you. Place all on a suitable work area. Turn off the lights and wait perhaps 15 minutes. This time-out allows your eyes to adapt.  Now you are in a position to judge if the area is truly dark. If you can see your hands or light coming from under or around the door, don’t proceed until you are sure you will be working in total darkness.

Now that it is safe to open the camera, you can manually remove the film and manually rewind the film into the cassette. If you fail to rewind back into the cassette, you can wind up the film without the cassette. Wrap the wound-up film with several layers of aluminum foil.  If you are careful, the foil will form a light tight seal.